# ifelse and append not working within a function

Tags: r, function, append

I want to distribute the names of files in two different vectors. If they exist, they should go to existing_files and if not, they should go to missing_files.

```
existing_files <- ""
missing_files <- ""

f1 <- function(file_name){
  if (any(file_name == vector_of_file_names)) {
    existing_files <- append(existing_files, file_name)
  } else {
    missing_files <- append(missing_files, file_name)
  }
}

f1("file1")
```

Executing "file1" does not work and i don't get any warning or error. Why is that? If i remove "existing_files <-" and "missing_files <-" in the function, i would get the correct result in the console. But i need it stored in the global environment.

A bit more information on what i am trying to solve here:

I am scanning the folder i am working with for file names i have stored in "vector_of_file_names". I just wanna know, if all the files i need are in that folder or not. I do that with list.files, which gives me all the files. Then i compare those files to "vector_of_file_names". The result is what is seen in my question. I want two vectors that list the files (that i want in that folder) according to their existence in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`existing_files` and `missing_files` are in the global scope. They can't be changed within the scope of your function without super-assignment `<<-`

```
existing_files <- ""
missing_files <- ""

f1 <- function(file_name){
  if (any(file_name == existing_files)) {
    existing_files <<- append(existing_files, file_name)
  } else {
    missing _files <<- append(missing_files, file_name)
  }
}

f1("file1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little more context on the problem you are trying to solve? I don't see anything in your code that actually tests for the "existence" of files, only the state of the vector `existing_files`.

It is unusual design choice to have a function which acts on a single object at a time and then potentially modifies state in one of multiple external objects depending on the result. Yes, you can "solve" your problem using exotic methods like out of superassignment (where objects in others scopes are modified as a side effect of your function) but your code will quickly become hard to reason about.

Comment: I am scanning the folder i am working with for file names i have stored in "vector_of_file_names". I just wanna know, if all the files i need are in that folder or not. I do that with list.files, which gives me all the files. Then i compare those files to "vector_of_file_names". The result is what is seen in my question. I want two vectors that list the files (that i want in that folder) according to their existence in that folder.

Comment: You can determine present files with `vector_of_file_names[vector_of_file_names %in% list.files()]` and absent files with `vector_of_file_names[!(vector_of_file_names %in% list.files())]`. You can e.g. put it into a function that returns a list with both present and absent if you like. Trying to encapsulate this logic in a function that has a bunch of side effects and modifies objects in the parent scope will lead to spaghetti code.